# Application closed on video recording without preview

Tags: android

> i have a service class in which i start recording without any preview but when service starts then the recording starts but application close..

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    // Create new SurfaceView, set its size to 1x1, move it to the top left corner and set this service as a callback
    windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            1, 1,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );
    windowManager.addView(surfaceView, layoutParams);
    surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST` to `LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` and make sure you have this permission set in your manifest file:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>`

TYPE_TOAST was deprecated in API 26